# jQuery to get block of text where cursor is on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m not sure if this is possible:

Click a button to get the block of text where cursor is currently on. Boundaries are determined by blank lines.

eg. the following text is inside a textarea of HTML code

```
This is paragraph one

This is paragraph two and carriage return here
This is line 2 of paragraph two
Some text [cursor is here] some text
Rest of the text

This is the paragraph three
```

When a button click, I would like to get the 4 lines of paragraph two.

The edge of the block is finished by a blank line at beginning and at ending.

For first paragraph and last paragraph, only one blank line is needed.

Cursor on means mouse clicked inside anywhere within a paragraph in a textarea field

I was using highlighted text and works. For tablet it is handy if also working when not highlighted.

Comment: Show us your HTML code and then the script what you have tried?

Comment: Hi John, I have updated the question with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.selectionEnd` to get the caret position (probably not supported in older IE)... then use it to find which paragraph the caret is in. Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/16rw01w1/):

HTML

```
<textarea id="source">...</textarea>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

Script

```
$(function() {
  var $source = $('#source'),
    $result = $('#result');

  function getParagraph() {
    var indx,
      strLength = 0,
      val = $source.val().split(/\r\r|\r\n\r\n|\n\n/),
      length = val.length,
      cursor = $source[0].selectionEnd;
    for (indx = 0; indx < length; indx++) {
      // add two more to get past the carriage returns
      strLength += val[indx].length + 2;
      if (strLength > cursor) {
        return val[indx];
      }
    }
  }
  $source.on('mouseup keyup', function() {
    $result.val(getParagraph());
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks working. I do not mind IE. As there is no IE in mobile / Tablet